# Solve $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{30}$ and generalize.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

This was one of the questions in a Olympiad number theory course. I used brute force with the CRT: x is odd, not divisible by 3 and its square leaves remainder 1 mod 5 (therefore $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$). So $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{30}$ or $x \equiv \pm 11 \pmod{30}$ . As it can be noted, this is extremely specific and, therefore, a little bit ugly.

How do I generalize this problem for an arbitrary $n$? For example, taking $n = 24$, we have that $5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$. So there must be a nontrivial pattern. How do I generalize it?

Comment: $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 24; (x -1)(x+1)\equiv 24$ so $(x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0\mod 3,8$  So $x\equiv \pm 1\mod 3$ and $x \equiv \pm 1; \pm 3 \mod 8$. So 8 answers $x \equiv 1\mod 3\equiv 1\mod 8\equiv 1\mod 24$ or $x\equiv 1\mod 3\equiv -1\mod 8\equiv 7\mod 24$ or $x\equiv 1\mod 3\equiv 3\mod 8\equiv 19\mod 24$ or $x\equiv 1\mod 3\equiv -3\mod 8\equiv 13\mod 24$ and the four negatives of those.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: write $$(x-1)(x+1)\equiv 0 \mod 30$$

Comment: I wrote it like this before and, since $\mathrm{gcd}(x-1, x+1)$ = 2, I concluded that $\frac{x-1}{2} \cdot \frac{x+1}{2} = 15y’$, where the factors on the LHS are coprime, but I couldn’t advance.

Comment: $\gcd(x-1,x+1) = 2$ what if $x$ is even?  Anyway $(x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0$ means $(x-1)(x+1)= k*30$.  What are the divisors of $30$?  If the divisors are coprime you can find them that are $2$ apart.

Comment: If $x$ is even then both $x-1, x+1$ are odd and then $(x+1)(x-1) = 2(15k)$ is odd. Absurd.

Comment: Oh, can't argue with that.....

Comment: I didn’t advance at all. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Well $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 30$ so $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1) \equiv 0 \mod 30$.

Now the trivial factors of $0$ are $0$ and anything else so $x \pm 1$ will do (and will do for any modulus).

Non trivial are $2k, 15$, $3k,10j$ and $5k,6j$.  Now we need two that are different by $2$. As each pair is relatively prime that can be done.

$2k - 15j = \pm 2$ however requires $j$ to be even which is equivalent to $0$ and is a trivial solution.

$3k - 10j = \pm 2$ is soulbe but $3*6 - 10*2 = -2$ so $(x-1)=18; (x+1) = 20; x = 19$ will do and $19^2= 18*20 + 1\equiv 6*2*30 + 1 \mod 30$.

For $5k - 6j =\pm 2$ there is $k=2; j = 2$and $x-1=10; x+1=12$ or $x = 11$ will do and $11^2 = 121 \equiv 1 \mod 30$.

So the solutions are $1,31,19, 11$ or $\pm 1; \pm 11$.

===

In hind sight is probably easier to use that Chinese remainder theorem.

$x^2 \equiv 1\mod 30 \implies x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 2,3,5$

So $(x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0 \mod 2,3,5$.  As $2,3,5$ are prime the only solutions are $1$ and $-1\mod 2,3,5$.

If $x \equiv \pm1 \mod 2;x \equiv 1 \mod 3; x\equiv 1 \mod 5 \implies x \equiv 1 \mod 30$ is a solution.

$x \equiv \pm1\mod 2; x\equiv 1 \mod 3; x \equiv -1 \mod 5 \implies x \equiv 19 \mod 30$.

$x \equiv \pm1\mod 2; x\equiv -1 \mod 3; x \equiv 1 \mod 5 \implies x \equiv 11 \mod 30$.

$x \equiv \pm 1\mod 2; x\equiv -1 \mod 3; x\equiv -1\mod 5 \implies x\equiv 29 \mod 30$.

So those are the $4$ answers.

That can be generalized to any square free composite numbers.

====

Putting it all together:

If $n$ is prime then $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod n\implies (x + 1)(x-1)\equiv 0 \mod n$ and for prime $n$ the only solutions are $x \equiv \pm n$.

If $n = p^k$ then $(x-1)(x+1)\equiv 0 \mod p$ so if $x \not \equiv \pm 1$ then $x+1, x-1$ are both powers of $p$.  This is only possible if $p = 2$.  Only one of $x \pm 1$ is divisible by $2$ so $x\pm 1 \equiv 2$ and $x \mp 1 \equiv 2^{k-1}$.  And $2^{k-1} -2 = 2$ so $k = 3$. And $x \equiv 3$.

So if $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 2^3$ then  $x\equiv \pm 1; \pm 3$

Other wise if $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod p^k$ then $x \equiv \pm 1\mod p^k$.

Finally if $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod n =\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then by CRT

$x \equiv \pm 1\mod p_i^{a_i}$ (or $\pm 3 \mod 8$).  And by CRT there will a a unique solution to all of the combinations.

So if $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 360 = 8*9*5$ then

$x \equiv \pm 1, \pm 3 \mod 8; x\equiv \pm 1 \mod 9; x \equiv \pm 1 \mod 5$.

So there are 16 solutions.

Comment: Upvoted. But there is a problem: how do we count how many solutions are there?

Comment: If $n=2^k\prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{a_i}$ is the unique prime factor of $n$ then $x =\equiv \pm 1 \mod p_i^{a_i}$ are $2^m$ systems of equations.  Each system has a unique solution.  If $k=1$ then $x\equiv 1\mod 2$ is a single equation and there are $2^m$ solutions.  If $k=3$ then $x\equiv \pm 1,\pm 3 \mod 8$ our four equations and there are $4*2^m$ solutions.  Otherwise $x\equiv \pm 1\mod 2^k$ is two equations and there are $2*2^m$ solutions.  So there are $2^i*2^m$ solutions where $m$ is the number of odd primes. $i=2,10$ depending on if the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$ is 3, not 3, or 1 or 0.

Comment: Oh, this can be guaranteed because of the CRY right?

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This method works only for primes $n$**

Let $0<a<b<n$ such that $a^2 \equiv b^2 (\mod n)$. Then, we have $(b-a)(a+b)\equiv 0 \mod 30$. Since $a<b<n$ and $n$ is a prime, $b-a$ cannot divide $n$. Thus we must have 
$$(a+b)\equiv 0 \mod 30\Rightarrow a \equiv -b \mod n$$

This means $b=n-a$. Thus we can conclude that only $a^2$ and $(n-a)^2$ can have the same remainder when divided by $n$.

Comment: $b-a$ is not necessarily coprime to $n$ so your argument fails.

Comment: I had this in mind, too. But it didn’t go so well...

Comment: @LucasHenrique Ah yes, this method works only for primes...

Comment: $11^2 = 4*30 + 1$.  $19^2 \equiv 1 \mod 30$>

Comment: @fleablood This is only for prime $n$

Comment: Since when has $30$ been prime?  You said, and I quote, "Coming to you case, we have $x=30k±1$ as the only solution to $x^2≡1\mod30$".  That is simply not true.  Because $30$ is not prime

Comment: @fleablood whoops sorry, I had forgotten to remove that part while editing. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

It is:
$$x^2=30n+1.$$
Obviously, $x=2k+1$.Then:
$$2k(k+1)=15n=15\cdot 2m \Rightarrow k(k+1)=15m.$$
There are $4$ cases:
$$1) \ k=3p, k+1=5q \Rightarrow 5q-3p=1 \Rightarrow (p,q)=(-2+5t,-1-3t) \Rightarrow x=2k+1=6p+1=30t-11.$$
$$2) \ k=5r, k+1=3s \Rightarrow 3s-5r=1 \Rightarrow (r,s)=(1+3t,2+5t) \Rightarrow x=2k+1=10r+1=30t+11.$$
$$3) \ k=15t \Rightarrow x=2k+1=30t+1.$$
$$4) \ k+1=15t \Rightarrow x=2k+1=30t-1.$$
Hence, the solutions are:
$$x=30n\pm 1; 30n\pm 11.$$